# Get records with HQL query between two dates

Tags: database, hibernate, hql

I'm trying to get an affordable car in the time period

`SELECT c FROM Car c WHERE c NOT IN (SELECT r.car from Rental r WHERE  r.startDateTime >= :startDate AND r.endDateTime <= :endDate)`

This query is invalid. For exmaple, my `endDate` my be more than `r.endDateTime`

I'm trying to fix this with **BETWEEN**, but my request is wrong

`SELECT c FROM Car c WHERE c NOT IN (SELECT r.car FROM Rental r WHERE :startDate OR :endDate BETWEEN r.startDateTime AND r.endDateTime)`

Comment: Why is your first query wrong?

Comment: @SimonMartinelli If the car will be rented from 12-00 to 18-00, and my `:starDate` will be 13-00 and `endDate` 17-00, then I can get this car. but this is wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query should look like this:

```
SELECT c FROM Car c 
WHERE c NOT IN (SELECT r.car FROM Rental r 
                WHERE (:startDate BETWEEN r.startDateTime AND r.endDateTime)
                   OR (:endDate BETWEEN r.startDateTime AND r.endDateTime))
```